# printing image cordinates on submit

Tags: php

```
<input type="image" name="myimage" src="desert.jpg" height="42" width="42"
        <?php
        $xcoord=$_POST['myimage_x'];
        $ycoord=$_POST['myimage_y'];
        echo "X=$xcoord, Y=$ycoord";
        ?>
```

Iam getting error as undefined index for myimage_x and myimage_y. I am a php beginner, I want to display the image coordinates after submit. 
Once the image is clicked and submitted coordinates should be displayed on the screen.

Comment: Add a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's actually getting submitted.

Comment: Are you using POST or GET for your phone method?

Comment: Close your input tag.

Answer (score 0):

you worte

```
<input type="image" name="myimage" src="desert.jpg" height="42" width="42"
```

please replace it

```
<input type="image" name="myimage" src="desert.jpg" height="42" width="42">
```

you forgot close input tag ">"

full code :

```
 <?php

        $xcoord=isset($_POST["myimage_x"]);
        $ycoord=isset($_POST["myimage_y"]);

        echo ("X :".$xcoord);
        echo ("Y :".$ycoord);
  ?>
```